# Streaming a remote file

Tags: c, linux, fmod

i'm new to fmod, and I'm trying to use it for a simple application.
I just need to open a remote music file (mostly mp3, and if that can help I can transcode on the server to always have mp3).

When I try to

```
FMOD_System_CreateSound(system, "http://somewhere.com/song.mp3", FMOD_SOFTWARE | FMOD_2D | FMOD_CREATESTREAM, 0, &song);
```

That works fine, it open and play the mp3 fine.

But, when I try to do what I realy need :

```
FMOD_System_CreateSound(system, "http://somewhere.com/somepage.view?id=4324324324556546456457567456ef3345&var=thing", FMOD_SOFTWARE | FMOD_2D | FMOD_CREATESTREAM, 0, &song);
```

It just don't works.
That link for example would return a stream.mp3 file, but FMOD just fail on it.
Is there a way to make it works ?
I guess the problem is FMOD just don't find the filename in the link, but I can't change the link :/

If it's not possible, is there a way to make fmod works with curl (curl download the file perfectly), like a function to call for each part of the file ?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know fmod (the one I know is for floating-point remainder). Try finishing the url with `".mp3"`. Maybe `"http://...&var=thing&dummy=dummy.mp3"`

Comment: Yeah, I already tied that, it's not working :/

Comment: @Ulrar use wireshark to figure out what's going out on the wire and e.g. what the http server responds with.

Comment: I just did that, the GET request from FMOD seems fine to me, and then the server send lots of TCP segment .. I guess that's fine, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with session ID based URLs is they can get quite long. Old versions of FMOD only supported 256 characters (causing truncation and failure to load), but any recent supported version allows up to 1024 characters.

I would recommend updating to a more recent version of FMOD and report back if you have any troubles.

Comment: Yes, the support told me that, I updated to 4.30 and now it works fine :-)